# Sorting Multidimensional Dict in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a sample json as :

```
{
"1_0": {
"stand": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "412.30"
    }
  ]
},
"exec": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "360.03"
    },
    {
      "rate": "360.03"
    }
  ]
}
},
"2_0": {
"stand": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "824.60"
    }
  ]
},
"exec": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "720.06"
    },
    {
      "rate": "720.06"
    }
  ]
}
},
"3_0": {
"stand": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "483.13"
    }
  ]
},
"exec": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "412.30"
    },
    {
      "rate": "412.30"
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

I have been trying to sort the dict in terms of "rate" tag with respect to keys "1-0","2_0" and so on   ,so that I have something like :


**Expected Output**:

```
{
"1_0": {
"exec": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "360.03"
    },
    {
      "rate": "360.03"
    }
  ]
},"stand": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "412.30"
    }
  ]
}
},
"2_0": {
"exec": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "720.06"
    },
    {
      "rate": "720.06"
    }
  ]
},
"stand": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "824.60"
    }
  ]
}
},
"3_0": {
"exec": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "412.30"
    },
    {
      "rate": "412.30"
    }
  ]
},
"stand": {
  "bk": [
    {
      "rate": "483.13"
    }
  ]
}
}
}
```

Below is the chunk of code I have tried ,although it doesn't seem right:

```
f = open('file.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 

for value in data.values():
    for x in value.values():
        for y in x.values():
            y.sort(key=lambda e: float(e['rate']))
```

What error am I making,also I know the nested for loops don't seem pythonic.

Comment: What is your expected output? You have "rate" keys in both `d[key]['exec']['bk']` and `d[key]['stand']['bk']` so how do you want to have it handled?

Comment: I have added the expected output above

Comment: @radix it does sorting correctly. You're missing some details.

Comment: @sonus21 what details?

Comment: @radix you're expecting dict to be sorted on rate key and that internal dictionary is sorted. FWIW dictionary does not maintain key orders, so your list is sorted here. So you must provide what's your expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure if I understand your need correctly, but here's a try.

Assuming `d` is your dict:

```
def subkey(subdict):
    return list(subdict)[0]

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = { k1: v[k1] for k1 in sorted(v, key=lambda x: v[x][subkey(v[x])][0]['rate']) }
```

Please note that it works only in Python 3.6+, before that dicts were not guaranteed to keep order.

Comment: What if the tag "bk" is dynamic,this code wouldn't work right?

Comment: No, of course not. You didn't mention any other possible values than `"bk"`.

Comment: my mistake , the value "bk" was sample ,it can be dynamic.

Comment: Is it stil just one subkey under both "exec" and "stand" keys, or are multiple subkeys possible? And if so, how does that affect expected sorting order?

Comment: Single subkey but the value is not static,rest of sorting is fine

Comment: Please see the edited version. It is getting ugly, but probably works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This code can help

```
for key, value in data.items():
    data[key]  = {'stand' : value['stand'], 'exec' : value['exec']} if float(value['stand']['bk'][0]['rate']) < float(value['exec']['bk'][0]['rate']) else {'exec' : value['exec'], 'stand' : value['stand']}
```

Return

```
{'1_0': {'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '360.03'}, {'rate': '360.03'}]},
  'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '412.30'}]}},
 '2_0': {'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '720.06'}, {'rate': '720.06'}]},
  'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '824.60'}]}},
 '3_0': {'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '412.30'}, {'rate': '412.30'}]},
  'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '483.13'}]}}}
```

Comment: The tags(stand,exec,bk) are dynamic, can't define them on code level.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
>>> {key:value for key,value in l.iteritems()}
{'2_0': {'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '824.60'}]}, 'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '720.06'}, {'rate': '720.06'}]}}, '3_0': {'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '483.13'}]}, 'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '412.30'}, {'rate': '412.30'}]}}, '1_0': {'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '412.30'}]}, 'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '360.03'}, {'rate': '360.03'}]}}}
#give your sorting condition as key argument to sorted() 
>>> {key:dict(zip(value.keys(),sorted(value.values(),key=lambda v1: v1['bk'][0]['rate']))) for key,value in l.iteritems()}
{'2_0': {'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '720.06'}, {'rate': '720.06'}]}, 'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '824.60'}]}}, '3_0': {'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '412.30'}, {'rate': '412.30'}]}, 'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '483.13'}]}}, '1_0': {'stand': {'bk': [{'rate': '360.03'}, {'rate': '360.03'}]}, 'exec': {'bk': [{'rate': '412.30'}]}}}
```